# regex for if condition in java

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

so i have this problem..
POLL followed by a combination of 10 As, Ds, or Ms (agree, disagree, maybe), follwed by a yes or no.  If the answer is a no, there must be a reason that should follow.

Capture the ff:

- The A, D, M answers
- The yes/no answer
- [The reason that follows a no]

//case insensitive

i came up to this regex

```
 POLL\s+([ADM]{10})\s+(yes|no\s+([a-z. ]+))
```

The string is: `POLL admaaadddm no no comment`

The output is:

```
combination --> admaaadddm
yes or no --> no no comment  //this should be fix, it must capture no only
reason --> no comment
```

my code:

```
    String message = "POLL admaaadddm no no comment";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("POLL\\s+([ADM]{10})\\s+(yes|no\\s+([a-z. ]+))"
            ,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);


    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);

    try
    {
        if (m.matches())
        {

            String combination = m.group(1);
            String yesno = m.group(2);
            String reason = m.group(3);

            System.out.println(combination);
            System.out.println(yesno);
            System.out.println(reason);

        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Don't waste time with a regex; just read and parse the poll line.

Comment: i have to do so. this is an assignment using regex.LOL

Comment: What's the question/dificulty?

Comment: I've added the homework tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use non capturing groups to avoid that the part matched by the alternation is stored in a capturing group.

`(?:...)` a non capturing group.

```
 POLL\s+([ADM]{10})\s+(?:yes|(no)\s+([a-z. ]+))
```

**Update**

Then I think you need to go for something like this:

```
POLL\s+([ADM]{10})\s+(?:(yes)|(no)\s+([a-z. ]+))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?305jt) (you can see the content of the groups when the mouse hovers over the match.)

The problem is, you have 4 capturing groups now. You can't avoid this in java, since the groups in the alternations are different ones.

So you would need to check if `group[2]` or `group[3]` are valid. If `group[3]` then there is also a `group[4]` with the comment.

`group[1]` contains always the ADM part

`group[2]` contains "yes" if there is "yes" otherwise NULL

`group[3]` contains "no" if there is "no" otherwise NULL

`group[4]` contains "the comment" if there is one otherwise NULL

Comment: POLL followed by a combination of 10 As, Ds, or Ms (agree, disagree, maybe), follwed by a yes or no. If the answer is a no, there must be a reason that should follow.

Capture the ff:

The A, D, M answers

The yes/no answer

The reason that follows a no

Comment: sorry but i dont get this. how can i capture the adm combination group, the yes or no group, and the reason group?

Comment: ive tried youre regex. its almost working. but when it captures no it returns null.

Comment: the yes|no must be in the same group not (yes)|(no)

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("POLL\\s+([adm]{10})\\s+(yes|no)\\s+([a-z. ]+)"
            ,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

then get group(1,2,**3**).

Comment: @TristanDiaz have you tried the regex in my answer? it gives you group1:a..m; group2:no; group3:no comment

Comment: it must be like this e.g. valid

     POLL AADAMMAADM yes
     POLL MMMMMMMMMM no The mayor should do a better job of minimizing power outages and traffic.

e.g. invalid (answers no without reason, ADMs don't add up to 10)

     POLL AAAAADDDMMMMMMAADD no Di kami close.
     POLL AAAADDDDMM no

Answer (score 0):

Try `POLL\s+([ADM]{10})\s+((yes|no)(\s+([a-z. ]+))?)` - we add a new group for `(yes|no)`. Its number will be 3 while reason's group will be 5. You do match optional text after `yes` but ignore it, which I guess should be OK.

**EDIT:**

By inserting the dollar sign `$` after `yes` you will prevent a match if there's anything after `yes`: `POLL\s+([ADM]{10})\s+((yes$|no)(\s+([a-z. ]+))?)`

**EDIT 2 (in response to @TristanDiaz):**

I wouldn't bet my life on it, but I'm afraid what you desire is not possible, at least with standard regex. On one hand, you want `no` and the explanation after it to always come together. This means a concatenation in the regex. On the other hand you want to capture only `yes` or `no` into one of your groups, which requires splitting `no` from the string after it somehow. You can't have it both ways at the same time. You will either have to do something outside of the regex (e.g. capture `no` and the text after it into a single group and split it with regular string functions outside of regex), or choose the capturing group from which to take the yes/no text depending on a condition. Either way, you need external code.

Regular expressions have a certain expressive power and not everything may be expressed with their help. For example expressions as simple as "n A-characters followed by n B-characters" or "arithmetic expression with correct nesting of parentheses" are not possible to express using regex.

If this was a practical task, I would suggest not using regex at all, but rather splitting the input string on first N spaces and validating each part separately using normal code.

Comment: ive gone to this solution.this works, but the regex must not match no if its not followed by a reason.

Comment: how about something like it will prevent a match if theres nothing after no?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the third capturing group is nested inside the second, so the reason will be captured as part of group 2 as well as group 3.
Try moving a parenthesis from the end of the regex to just after the 'no', i.e.
`POLL\s+([adm]{10})\s+(yes|no)\s+([a-z. ]+)`.

If group 2 equals "yes", just ignore anything that is matched by group 3, assuming there would be anything there.

## Edit

Ok, try this `POLL\s+([adm]{10})\s+(yes|no)(?:(?<=no)([a-z. ]+)|$)` [RegExr](http://regexr.com?305kf)

A no without a reason shouldn't match, and neither should a yes *with* a reason.
The capturing groups are constant too, i.e. group 2 always captures yes/no, group 3 always captures the reason.

Comment: when the group of yesno captures no it must be followed by a reason. no without reason is invalid. ex. POST admadmadmm no //invalid it must be POST admadmadmm no blablah.

Comment: your regex matches no without reason. it returns null

Comment: @TristanDiaz Ok, I've updated my answer. I think this should work, but IRL it would be so much easier just to use an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a conditional statement in your regex with a lookahead.

```
Pattern.compile("POLL\\s+([ADM]{10})\\s+((?=no)(no)\\s(.+$)|yes$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

This won't match a string which contains a comment after "yes", nor will it match a "no" without a comment. Use groups 1, 3 & 4 with "no" and 1 & 2 with "yes".

** EDIT **

The following regex should work, and will store the results in the correct groups. 1, 2 & 3 (Use group 4 if you want the "reason" without the leading white space).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("POLL\\s+([ADM]{10})\\s+(no|yes$)((?:(?<=yes)($)|\\s+(.*)))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: nice your regex works! can you explain to me this (no|yes$)((?:(?<=yes)($)|\\s+(.*))).

Comment: Sure. `(no|yes$)` matches either the word "no" or the word "yes" at EOL. Then there's a conditional statement `$?`, where the condition is a lookbehind assertion for the string "yes". If "yes" was found, next we want to match the end of line `$`, otherwise we look for the comment with `\\s+(.*)`. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("POLL\\s++([ADM]{10})\\s++(no|yesEURO)((!*(!<=yes)(€)|\n\s++(.*)))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE_VERY_HIGH);
```